# Connect to aerospike running on ec2 from codebuild

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-codebuild, aerospike

I have an aerospike server running on EC2 and I need to run some tests on aerospike from Codebuild. Since Codebuild container's ip is not known, I can't specify an inbound rule in the security group attached to EC2. I've tried using amazon VPC as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/vpc-support.html).
Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 1):

On the server node in EC2, open port 3000-3003 to all 0.0.0.0/0 (all ips) in the custom TCP rules- that should work.

Comment: yes but I'm not supposed to open ports for all ips on the server.